# Setting httpStrictTransportSecurity and contentSecurityPolicy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, content-security-policy

In my Spring Boot application, I have a security config class for which I am trying to set response security headers i.e. `httpStrictTransportSecurity` and `contentSecurityPolicy` which is not getting in response. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().deny()
            .xssProtection()
                .and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' '=== key ==='")
                .and()
            .referrerPolicy(referrerPolicy -> referrerPolicy.policy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN))
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
                .includeSubDomains(true)
                .maxAgeInSeconds(31536000);

}
```

After setting `contentSecurityPolicy` and `maxAgeInSeconds` to `31536000` we are still getting `strict-transport-security:max-age` as `15724800` not able to see `contentSecurityPolicy` in the response.

Comment: `31536000` is Spring Security's default, so it should not neccessary to change it. If you get `15724800` there must be another configuration with this value. Do you have more than one security configuration? Or is your application running behind a proxy, which changes the HTTP response header?

Answer (score 0):

For httpStrictTransportSecurity header to be active you need to set the requestMatcher for the this header.

```
 .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
 .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
```

Hence your configuration should look like this.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .headers()
            .frameOptions().deny()
            .xssProtection()
                .and()
            .contentSecurityPolicy("default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' '=== key ==='")
                .and()
            .referrerPolicy(referrerPolicy -> referrerPolicy.policy(ReferrerPolicyHeaderWriter.ReferrerPolicy.STRICT_ORIGIN_WHEN_CROSS_ORIGIN))
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .requestMatcher(AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE)
;

}
```